# Displaying most popular post by category in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, loops, categories

Good morning fellow coders!

Im having a little bit of trouble and I think its in the loop but Ive been combing the WP codex for days now and cant quite get it to work even though I know its right under my nose!

The objective is fairly simple.  Im trying to build a venue & live music review site that has roughly 30 categories, 6 of them are parents and the rest are children where the parents serve as all inclusive cats for the kids.  IE: Music (parent) covers Hip Hop, R&B, etc etc.  On the index I need to set it up so that the single most popular post excerpt (by view) in the parents and their associated kids show up as a headliner for each of the 6 primary categories.  I set up a getpostviews and setpostviews function in functions.php, the setpostviews function in single.php and Ive tried setting up 'category_name = #' in the query as thats supposed to include the children, Ive tried querying by 'cat_id = #', Ive tried getting them all and then excluding the ones I dont want and I keep getting the single most popular post so Im at a loss.

The site is currently at [chronic.spearzolutions.com](http://chronic.spearzolutions.com) and you can see the specific code I have for the get/set postviews, and the loops [here](http://pastebin.com/aWTDAYk0)

Im pretty sure Im just doing something wrong in the loop, but Im not too proud to admit that or ask for help.  Always and forever "still learning" is the name of the game

Thanks in advance
Nick

Answer (score 1):

Well I will start with counting the most popular posts first. To Do do that, let's enqueue some view count code in the single page ( Change is_single() with your preferable condition )

For example:

```
define('WS_META_COUNT', 'ws93_view_count');
if(!is_admin()){

    add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse3VideoSetView');
}

function wpse3VideoSetView($postId = null){
    // substitude / add / remove your video count conditions here.

    if(!is_single())
        return;
    $id = !empty($postId) ? $postId : get_the_ID();
    $current = ( int ) get_post_meta( $id , WS_META_COUNT , true);
    $current ++;
    update_post_meta( $id , WS_META_COUNT , $current );
}
```

Now, when querying, I can construct a query and print, for example:

```
$args = array('numberposts'  => -1,  /* get 4 posts, or set -1 for all */
                'orderby'      => 'meta_value',  /* this will look at the meta_key you set below */
                'meta_key'     => WS_META_COUNT,
                'order'        => 'DESC',
                'post_type'    => 'post'  /* Replace your post type here */,
                'post_status'  => 'publish');
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';

    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

It really depends on how you want to represent your data now. For sub-catagory posts, query for that. If you give me a clearer example, I can give you a better query.

Comment: Thank you much, but I figured it out.  I had already had a get and set postviews function that was working as planned, I just had to tweak my $args a bit to make it work properly.  Truth be told I made a rookie mistake, I just needed some time to come back to it an check again with unclouded eyes.  Cest la vie